# npx create-react-app does not recognize npm as a command and aborts installation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

Basically, when I run `npx create-react-app` I get this output

```sh
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts@0.9.x has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting myapp/ from C:\Users\dralc\Desktop\Projects\React Tutorials
Done.
```

This problem only seems to occur with git bash and not Powershell.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling node as well as using yarn create react-app and get the same output. What am I missing here? Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** The version of npm I'm using is `6.14.6`

Comment: As for path in windows (which I'm convinced is the problem after having seeing this a few times) , go to "Edit System Environment Variables", Under "User variables for <username>", select "Path" and edit". Add a new line for "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm".  save and exit. You need to re-open whatver console you were using (powershell), but then it should work.

Comment: @ippi I looked at the user variables and that line already exists in there. Is there anything else that could be wrong? Could it be the console I'm using that has an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Either node is not installed in your system, or may it's not added to your path variable.
Run the command `node -v` and verify if it displays the node version installed in your system.